# Backbone events with wildcards

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there a way to listen to all events of a namespace. So when I listen to an event like this:

```
app.vent.on('notification(:id)', function(type){console.lof(type)})
```

It will listen to all events likes this:

```
app.vent.trigger('notification:info')
app.vent.trigger('notification:error')
app.vent.trigger('notification:success')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Backbone typically fires a general `eventName` event, as well as `eventName:specifier` event. An example of this is `Model.change`, which allows you to listen to all changes, as well as changes to individual fields:

```
model.on('change', this.onAnyPropertyChanged);
model.on('change:name', this.onNamePropertyChanged);
```

Following this pattern in your code, you could trigger your events as follows:

```
app.vent.trigger('notification', 'info');
app.vent.trigger('notification:info');
```

And listen to the general event:

```
app.vent.on('notification', function(type){ 
  console.log(type);  //-> "info"
});
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15295885/184883) it is not possible to listen events with wildcards. But as you can listen to `all` this will work:

```
vent.on('all', function(evenName, options) {
  var type = evenName.split(/notification:/)[1];
  if (type) {
    console.log(type, options);
  }
});
```

Comment: This will work, but it's good to be aware of the performance repercussions: if your application is of non-trivial size and makes good use of the mediator (`vent`), there will be likely a **lot** of events triggered. The `all` handler will see a lot of traffic, and might cause an actual performance hit.

Comment: Interesting... I doubt this would ever come into play on desktop web, but you're right-- I would be curious at how it clocks in on mobile browsers?  Particularly Android handsets pre-ICS (< 4.0)

Answer (score 2):

I have written this helper:

```
export default class EventsHelper {
  static triggerNamespacedEvent(eventBus, event, args) {
    event.split(':').reduce((previous, current) => {
      eventBus.trigger(previous, current);
      return `${previous}:${current}`;
    });
    eventBus.trigger(event, args);
  }
}
```

To use this in your view you would do:

```
actionOne(argsOne){
    EventsHelper.triggerNamespacedEvent(this, 'click:chart:one', argsOne);
}

actionTwo(argsTwo){
    EventsHelper.triggerNamespacedEvent(this, 'click:chart:two', argsTwo);
}
```

To listen for these events you would do:

```
//Listen for all clicks
this.listenTo(view, 'click', (args) => {
    console.log(`clicked something: ${args}`); //output: clicked something: chart 
});

//Listen for all chart clicks
this.listenTo(view, 'click:chart', (args) => {
    console.log(`clicked chart: ${args}`); //output: clicked chart: one 
});

//Listen for fully qualified event
this.listenTo(view, 'click:chart:two', (args) => {
    console.log(`clicked chart two: ${args}`); //output: clicked chart two: evtArgs 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Warning: Listening to event namespaces on custom events may not work any more. For example, this does *not* work:

```
  @listenTo @app, 'session', -> console.log ".listenTo `session` triggered"
  @listenTo @app, 'session:login_success', -> console.log ".listenTo `session:login_success` triggered"

  @app.on 'session', -> console.log ".on `session` triggered"
  @app.on 'session:login_success', -> console.log ".on `session:login_success` triggered"
```

If I trigger 'session:login_success' on the `@app`, only the two specific events fire, not the namespace one.

Related github issue: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/2558