# Backbone.js catch events by RegEx?

Tags: backbone.js

I was looking around but could not find anything whether it's possible to add event listener by RegEx rule?

I.e.:

```
EventBus.trigger('catalog:filter');
EventBus.trigger('catalog:removed');
```

And I want to catch them in two different ways:
1) By binding directly on event i.e.:

```
EventBus.on('catalog:filter', callback);
```

2) By binding for RegEx test and catching all events of that type i.e.:

```
EventBus.on(/catalog/, callback);
```

The second one should catch and handle both events 'catalog:filter' and 'catalog:removed'. This is in a way the same as model "change" and "change:[attribute]" way to bind events. It doesn't nesseceraly have to be RegEx object to work.

Thank you

Comment: See my answer in this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295768/backbone-events-with-wildcards/15295885#15295885. The other answer specifies how to listen to events using regexes, but I think my solution is preferrable. Either way, should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your problems can be solved by namespacing backbone events. I use it in a major project as app wide event bus and it is doing marvels. You can find one of implementations in here [Backbone.namespaced-events](https://github.com/wheresrhys/backbone.namespaced-events) and here is Dereck Bailey post about dos/donts of event agregation [Revisiting The Backbone Event Aggregator: Lessons Learned](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/03/revisiting-the-backbone-event-aggregator-lessons-learned/)